# Angular Isolate Scope breaks down?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="controller" ng-controller="mainController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    <div class="matches" 
        positions="{{client.positions | filter:value}}" 
        select="selectPosition(pos)">

        <div class="match" 
            ng-repeat="match in matches" 
            ng-click="select({pos: match})"
            ng-bind="match.name">
```

Then, inside my `matches` directive I have

```
app.directive('matches', function()
{
    return {
        scope: {
            select: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.matches = [];
            attrs.$observe('positions', function(value)
            {
                scope.matches = angular.fromJson(value);
                scope.$apply();
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this, I can console log `scope.matches`, and it does change with the value from my input. However, the last div `.match` doesn't render anything! If I remove `scope: {...}` and replace it with `scope: true`, then it does render the result, but I want to use the `&` evaluation to execute a function within my main controller.

What do i do?

Comment: `select` in your scope definition lacks a a single quote, `'`

Comment: What? What do you mean?

Comment: it should be `scope: {select: '&'}` instead of `scope: `{select: '&}`

Comment: That was just a typo that I fixed right away! I forgot to close the quotation when I was typing the example here. Plus if that was the problem, Angular would throw all nasty errors, cause that is a syntax problem! The application runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scope.$watch` instead, you can watch the attribute `select` whenever changes are made from that attribute.

```
app.directive('matches', function()
{
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.matches = [];
            scope.$watch(attrs.select, function(value) {
              scope.matches = angular.fromJson(value);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Likewise, if you define `select` itself as a scope attribute, you must use the `=` notation(use the `&` notation only, if you intend to use it as a callback in a template defined in the directive), and use `scope.$watch()`, not `attr.$observe()`. Since `attr.$observe()` is only used for interpolation changes `{{}}`, while $watch is used for the changes of the scope property itself.

```
app.directive('matches', function()
{
    return {
        scope: {select: '='},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.matches = [];
            scope.$watch('select', function(value) {
              scope.matches = angular.fromJson(value);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The AngularJS Documentation states:

### $observe(key, fn);

> Observes an **interpolated** attribute.
>
> The observer function will be invoked once during the next $digest
>   following compilation. The observer is then invoked whenever the
>   interpolated value changes.

Not scope properties defined as such in your problem which is defining `scope` in the directive definition.

Comment: The `select` attribute is used to invoke a function from the main controller. Plus, that is not really my problem. I said the code would work just fine as it is if I use `scope: true`. The problem is IF i define my isolate scopes, then it breaks down.

Comment: Also, `$watch` is used to watch over scope, and `$observe` is used for attributes.

Comment: Read my update, you're partially right, but `$observe` is only invoked when there are changes in the interpolated values of the observed attribute not the scope properties.

Comment: But that is not my problem. Inside the directive, if I console log the value, it does change. The problem is the scope.matches is not assigned inside the HTML! It doesn't seem to have a value

Comment: You should have mentioned that earlier, change `ng-repeat="match in matches"` to `ng-repeat="match in $parent.matches"`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the isolated scope, you could use `$parse` instead of the `&` evaluatation like this:

```
var selectFn = $parse(attrs.select);
scope.select = function (obj) {
  selectFn(scope, obj);
};
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/QZy6TQChAw5fEXYtw8wt?p=preview

But if you prefer the isolated scope, you have to transclude children elements and correctly assign the scope of your directive like this:

```
app.directive('matches', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      select: '&',
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function (clone) {
        element.append(clone);
      });

      scope.matches = [];
      attrs.$observe('positions', function(value) {
        scope.matches = angular.fromJson(value);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/9SPhTG08uUd440nBxGju?p=preview